# How to create two tables in kivy , RecycleView

Tags: python, class, android-recyclerview, return, kivy

**Hello everyone**, I'm new in Kivy and i need your help .. 
i have a little question:

I'd like to make a table in Kivy  for Tow Class RV() & VV(), but I don't know how can i return to second Class RV() and see the result !! 
now i can just see VV() Class in Kivy Window , 
can you help me plz

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

Builder.load_string('''
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size:  None , dp(20)
        default_size_hint: 1 , None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'

<VV>:
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size:  None , dp(50)
        default_size_hint: 1 , None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]

class VV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(v)} for v in range(100)]

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return VV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
TestApp().run()
```

Thanks

Comment: Rather than just returning `VV()` in your `build()` method, consider creating a `ScreenManager` with two child `Screens`. The first `Screen` could contain `VV` as a child, and the other could contain `RV`. Then you just switch `Screens` to whichever you want to see.

Comment: hi John , 
can't i do it on the same screen?

Comment: Make a screen, make a layout there and add both of that RecycleViews to that layout. And in build method you should return that screen you've created.

Comment: Yes, as @Lothric says. His approach would show both `RV` and `VV` at the same time.